# How to `rearrange` values only if they are in a certain group?

Tags: r, dplyr

How would I go about conditionally reorganizing this data frame? I want for each of my groups of `ourid`, the `us` values to be at the top followed by each the same `comp` and their products sold (see second table). Currently, it lists all `tape` products then all `glue` products. I'd like it to look like the second table though where it switches off and the same compid are by each other.

So, basically I want to just reorganize the values with a `class` of `comp` and keep `us` at the top for each of our groups.

| ourid | class | compid | Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | us | NA | Tape |
| 1 | us | NA | Glue |
| 1 | comp | 101 | Tape |
| 1 | comp | 102 | Tape |
| 1 | comp | 103 | Tape |
| 1 | comp | 101 | Glue |
| 1 | comp | 102 | Glue |
| 1 | comp | 103 | Glue |
| 2 | us | NA | Tape |
| 2 | us | NA | Glue |
| 2 | comp | 201 | Tape |
| 2 | comp | 202 | Tape |
| 2 | comp | 203 | Tape |
| 2 | comp | 201 | Glue |
| 2 | comp | 202 | Glue |
| 2 | comp | 203 | Glue |

| ourid | class | compid | Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | us | NA | Tape |
| 1 | us | NA | Glue |
| 1 | comp | 101 | Tape |
| 1 | comp | 101 | Glue |
| 1 | comp | 102 | Tape |
| 1 | comp | 102 | Glue |
| 1 | comp | 103 | Tape |
| 1 | comp | 103 | Glue |
| 2 | us | NA | Tape |
| 2 | us | NA | Glue |
| 2 | comp | 201 | Tape |
| 2 | comp | 201 | Glue |
| 2 | comp | 202 | Tape |
| 2 | comp | 202 | Glue |
| 2 | comp | 203 | Tape |
| 2 | comp | 203 | Glue |

This code gets kind of close - Tape and Glue to switch between each other  - but doesn't organize it by IDs how I need.

```
data2 <-
  data %>%
  group_by(ourid) %>%
  arrange(compid)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to arrange the data first by `ourid`, then by `class` (descending), then by `compid`, then by `product` (descending). We're using descending for `class` and `product` because your desired order seems to be reverse alphabetical. If you have more than 2 categories of product or class, you could do a custom order by converting them to `factor` class and specifying the order of the levels.

```
data %>% arrange(ourid, desc(class), compid, desc(product))
```